# SQL - How to get the maximum value of each row by calculation involving multiple columns

Tags: sql, max, correlated-subquery

Each row of Table1 should find the largest value that includes multiple columns in Table1 and Table2 in the calculation.
Table1 consists of columns: ID, Code, Value1, Value2, Max_value
Table2 consists of columns: ID, Code, Perc1, Perc2

```
**Table1**

ID=1 (value1=1000, Value2=5000, Code=21);   Max_Value=? 
ID=2 (value1=2000, Value2=4000, Code=21);   Max_Value=?
ID=3 (value1=1000, Value2=5000, Code=21);   Max_Value=?

**Table2**

ID=25 (Perc1=5.2%, Perc2=3.5%, Code=21);    
ID=26 (Perc1=3.1%, Perc2=8.6%, Code=21);   
ID=27 (Perc1=2.5%, Perc2=3.4%, Code=21)


** Calculation**

formula:
    =[(1 ∗ 1)+(2 ∗ 2)]
              WHERE Table1.Code = Table2.Code

Max_Value (Table1.Id=1, Table2.Id=25) = 227
Max_Value (Table1.Id=1, Table2.Id=26) = 461 (max for ID 1)
Max_Value (Table1.Id=1, Table2.Id=27) = 195

Max_Value (Table1.Id=2, Table2.Id=25) = 224
Max_Value (Table1.Id=2, Table2.Id=26) = 406 (max for ID 2)
Max_Value (Table1.Id=2, Table2.Id=27) = 186

Max_Value (Table1.Id=3, Table2.Id=25) = 401
Max_Value (Table1.Id=3, Table2.Id=26) = 695 (max for ID 3)
Max_Value (Table1.Id=3, Table2.Id=27) = 313
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I tride corelated subquery, but results are not excpected:

Comment: SELECT T1.ID, 
        (
            SELECT MAX((T2.Value1 * T2.Perc1) + (T2.Value2 * T2.Perc2))
            FROM Table2 AS T2
            WHERE T2.Code = T1.Code
        ) AS Max_Value
        FROM Table1 AS T1

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want `join` and `row_number()`:

```
select t12.*
from (select t1.*, t2.*,
             (t2.perc1 * t1.value1 + t2.perc2 * t1.value2) as calc,
             row_number() over (partition by t1.id order by (t2.perc1 * t1.value1 + t2.perc2 * t1.value2) desc) as seqnum
      from table1 t1 join
           table2 t2
           on t1.code = t2.code
     ) t12
where seqnum = 1;
```

Your formula and explanation alludes to a `code` column in `table1`, although I don't see it in the sample data.

Comment: Thank you very much.
        I will try to insert this code. Otherwise the tables are much more complex. Here is a correction of the above information: **Table1**
    ID=1 (value1=1000, Value2=5000, Code=21);   Max_Value=? 
    ID=2 (value1=2000, Value2=4000, Code=21);   Max_Value=?
    ID=3 (value1=1000, Value2=5000, Code=21);   Max_Value=?